# (Ubuntu server) Can't choose a disk - what to do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-server

I was configuring my Ubuntu server system and couldn't go on, as I wasn't able to choose a disk.

[image: here's a photo]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Virtio for virtualization.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/virtio.4freebsd.html

Can you try to do make partition manually, or go to another terminal during installation `Alt-Fx` to look at hdd `lsblk` or what *dmesg* says?

Ubuntu had issues with Virtio but it was release 14, long time ago.

Comment: well, I created my vm with the virt-manager (command: virt-install), I don't know if Virtio is similar there :/

Comment: When automated partitioning fails. I would make partitions manually. First boot partition and second as a rootfs. Before reboot at the installation last stage I would check file under  `/boot/grub/device.map` and `/boot/grub/menu.list` if there are parameters of vda instead of sda. Another option would be if that fails to turn off virtio at VM configuration, make installation. There will be hdd represented as sda device. After installation change under previously mentioned files variables from sda to vda. Update initramfs, turn off machine, enable virtio and boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to allocate more space for a local disk, not 4Gb but standard 10Gb instead. It worked for me.